# Missing architecture x86_64 for MediaLibsDemo

Tags: architecture, ios7, xcode5, x86-64

I am using the following library for connecting to the Red5 server.
https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos.
It gives me the following error. How can I add the missing architecture to the following file? or some other solution?

```
on implementing it, I am getting the following error.
ld: warning: ignoring file /private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-
v9.1965/lib/libavutil.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file   
/private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-v9.1965/lib/libavutil.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-
v9.1965/lib/libavdevice.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
/private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-v9.1965/lib/libavdevice.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-
v9.1965/lib/libswscale.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file  
/private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-v9.1965/lib/libswscale.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-
v9.1965/lib/libavformat.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file 
/private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-v9.1965/lib/libavformat.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-
v9.1965/lib/libavcodec.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file 
/private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-v9.1965/lib/libavcodec.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-
v9.1965/lib/libavfilter.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file 
/private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-v9.1965/lib/libavfilter.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/MediaLibiOS/MediaLibiOS.a, 
missing required architecture x86_64 in file
/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/MediaLibiOS/MediaLibiOS.a (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav- 
v9.1965/lib/libavresample.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file  
/private/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/libav-v9.1965/lib/libavresample.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/CommLibiOS/CommLibiOS.a, 
missing required architecture x86_64 in    
file/var/root/Documents/RTMP/RTMP/lib/CommLibiOS/CommLibiOS.a (4 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BroadcastStreamClient", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTMPClient", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Found any solution? If yes, please post it here so that it might help others. :)

Comment: I had contacted their support team and they reverted back with new builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the library you're using was not built for 64 bit architecture. If that is indeed the case, you'll need to configure Xcode to only build for 32 bit (assuming you can't get a 64 bit version):

1. Specify the valid architectures in your target build settings to exclude 64 bit (arm64)
2. Set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO` (when debugging)

[image]

By default, when debugging, Xcode will only build the active architecture. So this means if you're testing on a 64 bit device or simulator, Xcode will try to build a 64 bit binary, which will be incompatible with your 32 bit library.